# How to make it work NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
```

was showing the error:

> Builder (Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (FirebaseMessagingService, java.lang.String)

Help me to solve this problem.

*I* *tried* `Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);`
and

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

**But it was not working in both API 23 and API 27.**

*Here is the code*

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;


public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String notification_title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String notification_msg = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id_01";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }


        Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
        intent.putExtra("user_id", from_user_id);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo1).setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX).setContentTitle(notification_title).setContentText(notification_msg).setContentInfo("Info").setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.gabwithus"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.5.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with error that you are facing?

Comment: I've tested your code and its working on API 23 and 26.

Comment: i am trying in API 27 also

Comment: Builder
(Context)
in Builder cannot be applied
to
(FirebaseMessagingService,
java.lang.String)   getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this, I think your problem is here: `details.useVersion '25.3.0'`

```
     configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.0'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @VijayaAditya if it is working please upvote the answer.

Comment: I dont have enough reputations

Comment: You don't need reputation to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat`. The `v7.app.NotificationCompat` was actually removed in [revision 27.0.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#27-0-0) and was never updated to support Notification Channels.

You should remove that line and instead import `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`, which does support Notification Channels.

Answer (score 0):

its work in all api Try this :

```
 public void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_enable_notification_icon)
                    .setColor(Color.parseColor("#5878f2"))
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(messageBody)               
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message",messageBody);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    if(Build.VERSION_CODES.O <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
        builder.setChannelId(createNotificationChannel());
    }

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(211, notification);
}

 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private String createNotificationChannel(){
    String channelId = "demo";
    String channelName = "My demo";
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    mChannel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
    return channelId;
}
```

Comment: builder.setChannelId(createNotificationChannel());  in this line setChannelId was showing error

Comment: replace your `import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;` with `import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;` @VijayaAditya

Answer (score 0):

Android version O and above need notification channel. here is one working example for you.getRequestCode method is for different notification so that they will not replace. you can use any number also. If you use same number notification will replace automatically, so I use a random number generator.

```
  private static int getRequestCode() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return 100 + rnd.nextInt(900000);
}


  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, getRequestCode()  /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(neplaiTile) // use your own title
            .setContentText(message)    // use your own message
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setBadgeIconType(Notification.BADGE_ICON_SMALL);


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(getRequestCode() /* Request Code */, notificationBuilder.build());
```