# NotificationCompat.Builder does not accept channel id as an argument

Tags: android, notifications

I am attempting to set up notifications in my android app, but NotificationCompat will not accept the channel id as an argument. In my gradle file I have

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
```

I have also created the channels in my Starter code as below.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_1, "Channel 1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);

        channel.setDescription("This is channel 1");

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if (manager != null) 
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

Finally, I have in the activity code.

```
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1)
```

......and that is where I find my issue. Android Studio is telling me that the signature block is incorrect. It is not accepting the channel id as a second argument. I have imported both v4, and v7 for the NotificationCompat and neither works. I have also tried

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = //continued code
```

I have used the below Android links, and I have not found a solution.

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java

I also have viewed two StackOverflow post, which are below, and still no solution for my case.

[NotificationCompat.Builder() not accepting Channel Id as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138762/notificationcompat-builder-not-accepting-channel-id-as-argument)

[NotificationCompat.Builder doesn't accept 2nd argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765964/notificationcompat-builder-doesnt-accept-2nd-argument)

I cannot figure out why this issue is present.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: It isn't accepting the second argument. The error line appears and when I hover over it, it reads Builder (Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (LoginActivity, java.lang.String).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer in this article.

[How to make it work NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256665/how-to-make-it-work-notificationcompat-builder-notificationbuilder-new-notific)

```
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
```